# Module functions with default arguments and namespaces?

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I want to collect a few generally useful function into a module my_module. These functions must have default arguments that are variables in the workspace. When I move these functions out from the main code to the module, and then import them into the main code, then I get an error since these default arguments cannot be found.

```
y = 1;
def f(x, y=y):
   s =  x+y
   return s

f(1)
```

And when f instead is imported from my_module we have

```
y = 1
from my_module import f

f(1)
```

How can I adjust this later code to work as the first one?

Comment: you'd have to change your module function quite a lot in order to do the hack. You'll need to inspect the file the function is called from, and parse it's global variables etc. The resulting code would be really ugly and non-pythonic. I'd reject such code during review. Instead, pass the variable to the function when calling it.

Comment: In general I also think that one should bring in information to a function through arguments and not through global parameters, and good you point that out. However, these functions I do is intended to simplify command line interaction with some other software. This means you do not like to type in standard arguments all the time. They should be there. But bringing in the information to the function through default arguments is more clear than just bring this information in through global parameters. That is how I think.

Comment: Let me briefly disencourage the use of the names of built-in functions like 'sum' as a name of a variable. Use sum_ instead.

Comment: I have changed variable name to s now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my_module.py:

```
y = 1

def f(x, y = None):
    if y is None:
        y = globals()['y']
    sum = x+y
    return sum
```

test.py

```
import my_module
my_module.y = 2
f = my_module.f
print(f(1))
```

Comment: interesting. but is mymodule.y = 2 not modifying it for all the files importing it as well ?

Comment: I think your intention with your example is to show that in the test you import my_module and change y from 1 to 2 and then you bring in a "modified f" with f=my_module.f. But the  function f() you have now is NOT modified. It still use y=1 that it had in the defining file my_module.py.  So f(1) is 2 also this time.  That means that the   line my_module.y=2 does not play any role... Namespaces are a bit tricky!

Comment: @janpeter you're right, I forgot how optional arguments work, I updated the code and now it works

Comment: @AnthonyPerot it will affect all imports, my_module.y is like global variable for whole application

Comment: Something here still tricky and soon try to formulate that in this example.

Comment: @mugiseyebrows 
Now a year later I try to make use of your solution and does not work.
Key seems to be that my_module after all is a file that is imported from a startup-file, i.e. not from Jupyter notebook.  It means that globals()['y'] is something else than when called rom Juptyer notebook...

Is there a way to address with globals() the "namespace"  from which the function f () is called rather than from where it is defined?

Comment: In principle I dealt with the same problem in another post and made clear the usefulness of using the Python class-concept to make this right, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71638954/how-to-divide-a-script-in-a-smaller-script-and-a-module-and-connect-to-workspace